# Swift Infinity in Int datatype

Tags: ios, swift

I see unlike Double, Int in Swift does not have infinity. Only thing we have is Int.max and Int.min which are actually numbers and (Int.max - 1) is not the same as Int.max. I need to perform operations such as:

```
//maximumDuration is Integer...width, widthPerSecond, currentWidth are CGFloat, all positive

width = max(CGFloat(maximumDuration) * widthPerSecond, currentWidth)
```

So if maximumDuration is Int.max, CGFloat(maximumDuration) * widthPerSecond may not be Int.max. Infact, comparisons may not be reliable due to overflow.

What's the way out to have true infinity when using Int datatype? One way would be to use Double instead of Int but that would require so many type casts everywhere else in the code.

Comment: I don't understand what you want here, Int has a clearly defined max and min values so how are you supposed to go beyond those values?

Comment: It's a legit question. Float types have special ways of representing out of range values like infinity. Binary Integer types do not.

Comment: There is just no way to implement randomly big values using fixed width binary numbers. If you need randomly big values, you have to use floating point arithmetics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the integer types are simple scalars. All the bits hold value (plus a sign bit for the signed variants.) There are no spare bits for marking things like NAN, (not a number) infinity, normalized/non-normalized.

There is simply no way to represent infinity with binary integer types. This is not unique to Swift. It is true of just about all different languages/platforms.

Floating point types use an IEEE format that reserves some bits for special cases like infinity.

You could create an enum with associated values that had cases for negative and positive infinity, NAN, and the like, but you'd have the same casting/code rework problems that you're trying to avoid with floats.

### Edit:

Interestingly, in Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) there **are** spare bits. I wonder if there is a standard for indicating special values like infinity in BCD?